# how to implement ajax in django app?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, google-app-engine

My issue is similar to that mention in

[use of ajax in django problem with the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989054/use-of-ajax-in-django-problem-with-the-code)

I tried the solution given into that but still i am not getting the response value. below is my code

```
chkAjax.html
------------

<html>  
<head>  
<script>   
function chkAjax(form)  
{        
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);    
                document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/sign?text="+form.text1.value,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
function DoNav(theUrl,form)
{
      theUrl = theUrl + '?text=' + form.text1.value;
      document.location.href = theUrl;
}
</script>  
</head>
<body>   
<form method="get" action="">  
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="t1" onkeyup = 'chkAjax(this.form)'/>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is code for my handler

```
from django.http import HttpResponse  
c=self.request.get('text')  
c=c + "b"  
self.response.write("hi")
```

Using alert() I came to know that I am getting the response but with null value so please help me into this

Comment: hi all, I got solution to this problem so no need to reply thnks to all

Comment: close question or find best answer ;)

Comment: how to close the que?? i dont kn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

best example to find ajax in django

- http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/